# if else in spark passing an condition to find the value from csv file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to read csv file into dfTRUEcsv

How to get the value (03,05) and 11 as string in the below eg
I want to pass those string as a parameter to get files from that folder

```
i will pass (03,05) and 11 as parameters 
if TRUE , for each Loop start Folder\03 ;
                              Folder\05 ;   


Folder\11
```

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
|Calendar_year|Calendar_month|EDAP_Data_Load_Statu|lake_refined_date|isreload|
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
|         2019|             2|                HIST|         20190829|   FALSE|
|         2019|             3|                HIST|         20190829|    TRUE|
|         2019|             4|                HIST|         20190829|   FALSE|
|         2019|             5|                HIST|         20190829|    TRUE|
|         2019|            11|                HIST|         20190829|   FALSE|
+-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
```

```
       if the file has column isreload =='TRUE' 
                    var Foldercolumn Calendar_month 
                     Foldercolumn =     03
                     Foldercolumn =     05


      else
                 var Foldercolumn  max(Calendar_year ),max(Calendar_month )
                       Foldercolumn =     11

      end if
```

below is my spark code for the above requirement

```
val destinationContainerPath= "Finance/Data"
val dfCSVLogs = readCSV(s"$destinationContainerPath/sourcecsv.csv")

val dfTRUEcsv = dfCSVLogs.select(dfCSVLogs.col("*")).filter("isreload =='TRUE'")
```

Comment: can you explain with words what's the behaviour you want ?

Comment: could you provide expected output dataframe

Comment: I need to loop datafram and find the TRUE vaue in a column and based on that I need to take the action . If true "do something else "do nothing"- Code should be in scala.

Answer (score 0):

```
//read input control CSV file 
    scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("file.csv")
    scala> df.show(false)
    +-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
    |Calendar_year|Calendar_month|EDAP_Data_Load_Statu|lake_refined_date|isreload|
    +-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
    |2018         |12            |HIST                |20190829         |FALSE   |
    |2019         |2             |HIST                |20190829         |FALSE   |
    |2019         |3             |HIST                |20190829         |TRUE    |
    |2019         |4             |HIST                |20190829         |FALSE   |
    |2019         |11            |HIST                |20190829         |FALSE   |
    |2019         |5             |HIST                |20190829         |TRUE    |
    +-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+
    //initialize variable for max year and month 
    //note: below execution cam be modified on the basis of your requirement simply use filter to get max of particular condition

    scala> val maxYearMonth =  df.select(struct(col("Calendar_year").cast("Int"), col("Calendar_month").cast("Int")) as "ym").agg(max("ym") as "max").selectExpr("stack(1,max.col1,max.col2) as (year, month)").select( concat(col("year"), lit("/") ,col("month"))).rdd.collect.map( r => r(0)).mkString
           res56: maxYearMonth = 2019/11

    //Adding column temparary in input DataFrame
    scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("strFoldercolumn", when(col("isreload") === "TRUE", concat(col("Calendar_year"), lit("/"),col("Calendar_month"))).otherwise(lit(maxYearMonth)))
    scala> df2.show(false)
    +-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
    |Calendar_year|Calendar_month|EDAP_Data_Load_Statu|lake_refined_date|isreload|strFoldercolumn|
    +-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
    |2018         |12            |HIST                |20190829         |FALSE   |2019/11    |
    |2019         |2             |HIST                |20190829         |FALSE   |2019/11    |
    |2019         |3             |HIST                |20190829         |TRUE    |2019/3     |
    |2019         |4             |HIST                |20190829         |FALSE   |2019/11    |
    |2019         |11            |HIST                |20190829         |FALSE   |2019/11    |
    |2019         |5             |HIST                |20190829         |TRUE    |2019/5     |
    +-------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------+-----------+


    //move value of column strFoldercolumn into strFoldercolumn list variable 
    scala> val strFoldercolumn = df2.select("strFoldercolumn").distinct.rdd.collect.toList
    strFoldercolumn: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = List([2019/5], [2019/11], [2019/3])

    //lopping each value
    scala>strFoldercolumn.foreach { x =>
         | val csvPath =  "folder/" + x.toString + "/*.csv"
         | val srcdf = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(csvPath)
         | // Write logic to copy or write srcdf to your destination folder
         | 
         | }
```

Comment: How to get the value 03 and 11 as string

Comment: I want to pass those string as a parameter to get files from that folder

Comment: for eg:
i will pass the 03 and 11 as parameters

if TRUE ,
for each Loop start 
Folder\03

else
Folder\11

Comment: update the for each loop with example in the main chat.. hope it clarifies

Comment: Could you clear your requirements, do you want  to hardcode 3,5 and 11 then let me known how will you decide it should b 3 or 5 in case of True. As much as I understand, in case of True the value of Foldercolum  should be corresponding value of calendar month and in case of  False it should b Mac of year and month across all records.please confirm.

Comment: Spark does not work the way you are loopping it. And it is also not a good practice. For that you need to add new column first as I have done in my answer and after it you can get value of Foldercolum in a list for all True value and single value for False. But after it what do you want to do with these variables. Do you want to create new data frame on the basis of all records?

Comment: My Requirement : 
I have csv file in azure blob storage which contains the above details. Based on TRUE / FALSE i have to take the Year\Month and pass as a parameter to find source folder for copy activity  as part of string "Folder\Year\Month\*.csv" .

Pass these parameters as source string in loop to collect the files present in the folder and paste in my destination folder.

I donot need to update the csv with new column "Foldercolumn".  I will be fine if i get the values in loop to get the source string

Comment: @Raj check above code as a reference for your requirement

Comment: Getting error 
<console>:29: error: ';' expected but 'val' found.
         | val month = x(0)
           ^

Comment: Also, i will remove the duplicate post.. since we can continue here only..
What is the print val syntax..
Eg: maxCalendar_year.show() or maxCalendar_year.print is not working

Comment: check above code the error is occurring because you might have missed space and something. and for checking value of any variable check println(variable name)